# Component props is not being updated in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, use-state

```js
import React,{useEffect} from 'react'
import { Pin, Group } from './Pin';
import Cluster from './Cluster';

function ClusterGroupMain({textAsIcon,iconStyle,mapRef,onViewportChange,dataSet,icon,onClick,clickedMarkers }) {
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("Marker clicked-->>",clickedMarkers)
    })
    if(!mapRef || !dataSet) return null;
    return <div>
        <Cluster
            // props
        >
            {dataSet.map((dataPoint, i) => (
                <Pin
                    markerIndex = {i}
                    iconStyle={iconStyle}
                    onClick={onClick}

                    markerClicked={clickedMarkers&&clickedMarkers.length>0?clickedMarkers[i]:null}
                />
            ))}
        </Cluster>
    </div>
}

export default ClusterGroupMain
```

`onClick={onClick}` This statement updates `clickedMarkers`  props very well as i have checked using console.log `console.log("Marker clicked-->>",clickedMarkers)`.

`clickedMarkers` is array of booleans. Initially all value will be false.

#### ./Pin

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Marker } from 'react-map-gl';

export class Pin extends Marker {
  render() {
    const {key,longitude,iconStyle,latitude,marker,markerIndex,onClick,markerAltText,markerClicked} = this.props
    let iconHeight = iconStyle?iconStyle.height:"40px";
    let iconWidth = iconStyle?iconStyle.width:"40px"
    return (
      <Marker key={key} longitude={longitude} latitude={latitude} offsetLeft={-10} offsetTop={-10}>
        <img style={{height:iconHeight,width:iconWidth}} src={marker} onClick={(e)=>onClick(e,markerIndex)} ></img>
        {
          !markerClicked&&markerAltText?<div style={{
            // some styling
          }}>
            <p>{markerAltText}</p>
          </div>:null
        }
      </Marker>
    );
  }
}
```

`markerClicked` in ***Pin*** component never gets updated. It's value always remains false. As react docs if state or props changes then the component will rerender with new values.

In ***ClusterGroupMain*** component clickedMarkers always gets updated. I have checked using `console.log()`. And, i am passing `clickedMarkers[i]` as **markerClicked** prop for every **Pin** component.

So, the problem is why `markerClicked` doesn't gets update if `clickedMarkers`  does.

> I have checked `markerClicked` using **React dev tool**, it always remains false while `clickedMarkers` ulways updates.

Comment: Can we see your onClick function?

Comment: `onClick={()=>{ setClickedMarkers(prevState=>prevState.map((item,idx)=>idx==i?(!item):item)) }} `

Comment: @EricSvitok Above code is triggered on onClick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your are not creating a new array instance when updating the clickedMarkers array. If you mutate the array directly, react will not know the property has changed.

Try using the spread operator to create a new array instance when updating the clickedMarkers state in the onClick function.

```
onClick = (e, markerIndex) => {
    clickedMarkers[markerIndex] = True; // change value logic
    this.setState({clickedMarkers: [...clickedMarkers]}); // spread operator to create new array instance
}
```

Comment: I am creating new array instance on every onClick.

Comment: See -->> `onClick={()=>{ setClickedMarkers(prevState=>prevState.map((item,idx)=>idx==i?(!item):item)) }}`

Comment: As i mentioned `onClick={onClick} This statement updates clickedMarkers props very well as i have checked using console.log console.log("Marker clicked-->>",clickedMarkers)`. So, if `clickedMarkers` can be updated then `markerClicked` should also gets updated.